# how to update a table coulmn using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the fiddle there is a form which accpets mobile number and message text.Also there is a table which has message ,number, time and status.So when the send button is clicked then in the table rows are inserted and by default status column will show sending.I am using ajax to pass the number and message which then calls a servlet and ultimately calls a SMS api.If the message is sent then i wanted to change the status sending to sent.Please tell me how to do that.This is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fudv/)

this is the ajax

```
 $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "messageSending", //Your full URL goes here
                    data: { toNumber: number, body: msg},
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        //alert(data);   
$('#myModal').modal({show:true})
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR){
                        alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                    }
                });
```

What should I write in the success part of the ajax so that **sending** status will be changed to **sent**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#mytable1")//go to table
.find("td:contains("+number+")")// find td which conatin text like number
.closest("tr")// then go its respective **tr**
.find("td:last")// then go to last column
.text("sent");//then change text sending to sent
```

reference **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** , **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.Well will it work for multiple rows.I mean to say that suppose i sent 2 messages now.Out of that 1 is delivered now and another after 2 hours.So will the status of the 2nd one will change to sent after 2 hours

Answer (score 1):

You should add one unique & dynamic id to each row instead of same id and once you get response message "sent" for sms you can simply apply with jQuery like below

```
jQuery('#'+DynamicID).find('td:last-child').text('Sent');
```

You must need to identify every row with SMS response in order to change status for respected SMS Message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion,+1 for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#mytable1 tr'). children('td:last').text('sucess')
```